# All browsers refusing to load a specific image on a webpage?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, browser, html

Out of nowhere today, all 3 of my browsers (FF/Chrome/IE, OS = Win7 x64) are refusing to load the homepage of [interfacelift.com](http://www.interfacelift.com) correctly.  It works fine on other PC's in the house (on the same network), so it is definitely related to this one PC.  The browser won't load the main image on the page correctly (even though the source code looks good), however if I direct the browser to the [exact location](http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/previews/03115_greenlighthouse_medium@1x.jpg) of that image, then it displays fine.  So obviously I can get the HTML index (which locates the resource) and I can get to the resource.  So why heck isn't it displaying properly on the index page?  It's almost as if the HTML rendering engine has gone bad, on all 3 browsers at once.  I've browsed to a bunch of other sites (including sites very heavy on JS, with HTML much more complex than the one in question here) and am seeing nothing funny.

Only thing wonky I've done with my PC in the past several hours was replacing the system file `Magnifier.exe` with a copy of `cmd.exe` while playing around with some of the ideas mentioned in [this guide](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/general/game-over!-gaining-physical-access-to-a-computer/).  However, I've since then restored the files to their previous state, and I don't know how Magnifier would be related to this even if I hadn't restored it.

Any ideas?  I'm stumped!

EDIT: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9bJW.png) is what the broken page looks like in Chrome.  And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDrqS.jpg) is the image loaded correctly by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not you, it's them.

[interfacelift.com](http://interfacelift.com) chooses the image based on your browser window size:

- If the window's inner width measures less than 1366 pixels, it assumes you have a low screen resolution and it loads [03115_greenlighthouse_medium@1x.jpg](http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/previews/03115_greenlighthouse_medium@1x.jpg).

  This works just fine.
- If the window's inner width measures 1366 pixels or more, it assumes you have a high screen resolution and it attempts to load [03115_greenlighthouse_large@1x.jpg](http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/previews/03115_greenlighthouse_large@1x.jpg).

  However, this image does not exist. Trying to open it in a separate tab also results in a 404.

Comment: Ah very good, how did you located the problem so quickly?  I see the JS now that controls this, now that I know what to look for. :-)  Thanks!

Comment: My internet connection is quite slow, so I saw the image for a brief moment before it disappeared.